# how to stop js execution with function inside another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stop the js execution if the validate function returns false. However, if it's false, the script doesn't stop and I can se the message "This will run??" - Would someone give me a hint as to why calling the `validate()` function inside `submit()` doesn't work? What's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
// validate name
function validate(name){
    if(name.length < 1){
        console.log('false - length: ' + name.length);
        return false;
    }
}

// submit function
function submit(){
    var name = '';

    // if name is empty, the script should stop.
    validate(name);

    console.log("This will run??");
    return true;
}

submit();
```

Comment: It does work. It just doesn't do what is *incorrectly* expect: `return` only applies to the function body it appears in.

Comment: you want `if (!validate(name)) return false;` And you also need to `return true` at the end of `validate` when the check passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function validate(name){
  if(name.length < 1){
      console.log('false - length: ' + name.length);
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

your validate function should return true (otherwise it returns undefined, which is falsy)

```
function submit(){
    var name = '';

  // if name is empty, the script should stop.
  if(validate(name)) {
    console.log("This will run??");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```